# $.each saving all items into object array

Tags: jquery

I have written this jquery code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var university = { title: 0, href: 1, link: 2 };
        var universities = [];
        $(".aname").each(function (key, value) {
            university.href = value.all[0].href;
            university.title = value.all[0].innerHTML;
            university.link = value.parentNode.all[2].all[0];
            universities[key] = university;                
        });
       debugger; // now if you watch universities this only last item.
    });
</script>
```

It should save all university objects in to array of universities it works but it replace only the last item in to all items after $.each I don't know why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `all` collection is not cross-browser. Why are you using it? You got jQuery.

Comment: @kamiar3001  can you please give some context (in the form of HTML) around this code? It would really be helpful to me to understand the code. If you can paste the HTML on which you are trying to run this script here (http://jsfiddle.net/5zV29/1/), we can take a look at what's happening. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var universities = $( '.aname' ).map(function () {
    return {
        href: this.all[0].href,
        title: this.all[0].innerHTML,
        link: this.parentNode.all[2].all[0]       
    };
}).get();
```

However, I don't think the `all` collection is cross-browser. In that case, consider replacing it by jQuery's traversing methods, or native ones. For instance, if `all[0]` selects the first child (does it?), then you can write `this.children[0]` or `$( this ).children( ':first' )`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you modify the global university object instead of creating new one. Note that when you use operator '=' javascript copy reference to object not the object. If you like to deep copy of the object you can use jQuery.extend function.

Try this:

```
var universities = [];
$(".aname").each(function (key, value) {
    var university = {};
    university.href = value.all[0].href;
    university.title = value.all[0].innerHTML;
    university.link = value.parentNode.all[2].all[0];
    universities[key] = university;                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may need to use the .push() function of your array to add items to it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var university = { title: 0, href: 1, link: 2 };
    var universities = [];
    $(".aname").each(function (key, value) {
        university.href = value.all[0].href;
        university.title = value.all[0].innerHTML;
        university.link = value.parentNode.all[2].all[0];
        universities.push(university);                
    });
   debugger; // now if you watch universities this only last item.
});
```